# How to use the imbalanced library with sklearn pipeline?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sampling

I am trying to solve a text classification problem. I want to create baseline model using `MultinomialNB`

my data is highly imbalnced for few categories, hence decided to use the [imbalanced](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io) library with sklearn pipeline and referring the [tutorial](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/auto_examples/pipeline/plot_pipeline_classification.html#).

The model is failing and giving error after introducing the two stages in pipeline as suggested in docs.

```
from imblearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from imblearn.under_sampling import (EditedNearestNeighbours,
                                     RepeatedEditedNearestNeighbours)
# Create the samplers
enn = EditedNearestNeighbours()
renn = RepeatedEditedNearestNeighbours()

pipe = make_pipeline_imb([('vect', CountVectorizer(max_features=100000,\
                                         ngram_range= (1, 2),tokenizer=tokenize_and_stem)),\
                         ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(use_idf= True)),\
                          ('enn', EditedNearestNeighbours()),\
                          ('renn', RepeatedEditedNearestNeighbours()),\
                          ('clf-gnb',  MultinomialNB()),])
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Last step of Pipeline should implement fit. '[('vect', CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', binary=False, decode_error='strict',
```

Can someone please help here. I am also open to use different way of (Boosting/SMOTE) implementation as well ?

Comment: Is this the MultinomialNB you're importing? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html

Comment: @FilipeAleixo..Yes

Comment: Have you trying making a standard sklearn pipeline, to see if the problem is with imblearn?

Comment: standard sklearn pipeline is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you show your make_pipeline_imb function?

Comment: Its getting imported from from imblearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the pipeline from ìmblearn doesn't support naming like the one in sklearn. From [imblearn documentation](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.pipeline.make_pipeline.html) :

> *steps : list of estimators.

You should modify your code to :

```
pipe = make_pipeline_imb( CountVectorizer(max_features=100000,\
                                         ngram_range= (1, 2),tokenizer=tokenize_and_stem),\
                         TfidfTransformer(use_idf= True),\
                         EditedNearestNeighbours(),\
                         RepeatedEditedNearestNeighbours(),\
                         MultinomialNB())
```